# Parametric Continuous Convolution Layer: Formula explained

Tags: machine-learning, convolution, neural-networks

while reading the [Deep Parametric Continuous Convolutional Neural Networks](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Wang_Deep_Parametric_Continuous_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf) paper, I struggled to understand the formula for their **parametric continuous convolution layer**  (page 2) :
$$
\large{
h_{k,i} = \sum_d^F \sum_j^N g_{d,k} (\textbf{y}_i - \textbf{x}_j) f_{d,j}
}
$$

*My understanding*:
As far as I understood there are $N$ $F$-dimensional input feature vectors, i.e., $\large{f_{d,j} \in \mathbb{R}^{F \times N}}$  is matrix where each column corresponds to a one input feature vector $\large{\textbf{f}_{\mathrm{in,j}}}$.
Each of these vectors has an associated location in the support domain $\large{\mathcal{S} = \{\textbf{y}_j \}_{j=1}^N}$. Furthermore, the output domain locations $\large{\mathcal{O} = \{\textbf{x}_i\}_{i=1}^{O}}$ need to be provided as an input, where $O$ defines the number of output features.

However that would only make sense if they actually meant:
$$
\large{
h_{k,i} = \sum_d^F \sum_j^N g_{d,k} (\textbf{x}_i - \textbf{y}_j) f_{d,j}
}
$$
which would also make sense in relation to their previous approximation, where they use the following notation
$$
\large{
h(\textbf{x}) \approx \sum_{i=1}^N \frac {1}{N} f(\textbf{y}_i) g(\textbf{x} - \textbf{y}_i)
}
$$

Anyway, I have the feeling that I misunderstood something and I would appreciate any help.